# How to count the number of particular vowels from a string

Tags: string, f#

I am new to F# and I am creating a program that gives the number of Vowels in a given string and the number of particular vowel repeated in that string. I implemented the following code but I keep on getting the errors. Can anyone show a better way to do this.

```
#light

  let count_letter targetChar = Seq.fold (fun count ch -> if ch = targetChar then count + 1 else count) 0
  [<EntryPoint>]
  let mainargv =
      printf "input> "
      let input = System.Console.ReadLine()
      let text = input;
      let ch1 = 'a'
      let ch2 = 'e'
      let ch3 = 'i'
      let ch4 = 'o'
      let ch5 = 'u'
      let vowels = ['a';'e';'i';'o';'u']
      let if_vowel =
          fun c -> vowels |> List.contains c          
      0
```

Comment: In case you haven't already found it, you might find it useful to take a look at [this page on F#'s Map type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map-module-%5Bfsharp%5D), where they show how you might perform something like this.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin Can you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically correct. This is another way of doing the same:

```
let inline (|>!) v f = f v ; v // tee operator

let vowels     = ['a';'e';'i';'o';'u']
let if_vowel c = vowels |> List.contains c

text
|>   Seq.filter if_vowel
|>! (Seq.length >> printfn "vowels: %d")
|>   Seq.countBy id
|>   Seq.sort
|>   Seq.iter (fun (c, n) -> printfn "%c: %d" c n)
```

The output is similar but not exactly the same as yours because it only shows those vowels that are present.